# Keep getting error when starting react app

Tags: reactjs, npm

[image: react error]

I setup react using create-react-app - `npx create-react-app frontend` and then ran `npm run start` to get this error. found a few similar questions here that told to run `npm cache clean --force` but still isnt working. other npm packages are installing properly. any help would be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: did you use `npm install` before the `npm run start`?

Comment: can you add the code of the `index.js` to the question?

Comment: @MartinGainzaKoulaksezian no i did not. i am installing it using create-react-app so do i have to do npm install after it?

Comment: @RukshanJayasekara i didnt edit index.js at all. its the same as what is created after running `npx create-react-app`.